# Sorting a string without sort()/sorted() functions

Tags: python, string, sorting

I need to sort a four-number string into the highest and lowest value numbers that can be made using the digits in string. I cannot use sort() or sorted() functions. It was hinted that I should use the min(), max(), and len() functions. Can anyone help me figure out how to go about sorting the string? My current code is below using the sorted() function.

```
num = input("Enter a four-digit integer: ")

#setting intial value of iterations
i = 0

#differentiating between initial input value and transformed number
kaprekar = num

#while loop performing kaprekar's method
while (kaprekar != '6174'):
    i +=1
    #add leading zeros 
    kaprekar = kaprekar.zfill(4)
    #Sorts to largest and smallest number made from input number
    num1 = ''.join(sorted(kaprekar,reverse=True))
    num2 = ''.join(sorted(kaprekar))
    difference = str(int(num1) - int(num2))
    print(kaprekar, "> ", end='')
    #reassigns number for loop
    kaprekar = difference

print(kaprekar)
print(num, "reaches 6174 via Kaprekar's routine in", i, "iterations")
```

Comment: `max(int(''.join(x)) for x in itertools.permutations('6174', 4))` → `7641`

Comment: That's a bit overkill, though. Hint: `max('6174') = '7'`. So remove '7', add it to a new string, repeat.

Answer (score 0):

To find minimum/maximum number from the string (without `sorted()`):

```py
s = "6174"

out = ""
while s:
    out += min(s) # or max() for maximum
    s = s.replace(out[-1], "", 1)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
1467
```